# Test if livepatch is working

Tags: kernel, canonical-livepatch

I enabled livepatch on machine and I would like to test if it will work as expected. But there is no update to test it.

Can I install some older kernel to test or find a way to make sure it works?

```
canonical-livepatch status --verbose
last check: 12 minutes ago
kernel: 5.15.0-87.96-lowlatency
server check-in: succeeded
kernel state: ✓ kernel series 5.15 is covered by Livepatch
patch state: ✓ no livepatches available for kernel 5.15.0-87.96-lowlatency
tier: updates (Free usage; This machine beta tests new patches.)
client version: 10.7.0
architecture: x86_64
cpu model: AMD Ryzen 9 3900 12-Core Processor
boot time: 3 days ago
```

Comment: I can only think of one issue to this and that is that the Kernels on the servers that supply them have probably been patched already.  So unfortunately, a test like this might always fail on older kernels.

Comment: Downgrade to the previous kernel version, then try running livepatch?

Comment: Downgrade to 5.15.0-84.93-lowlatency and still nothing to patch